# Website UI using CSS

Tags: css

Where should I start off to create cool web interfaces or UI's for my websites. Is CSS alone enough to create these webinterfaces or is there more to it? I'm interested in creating reusable UIs for future projects as well. So how do i get started? Thanks in advance! :) :)

Cheers
Jay

Answer (score 2):

maybe try jQuery UI?

have a look at the demos page and see if it fits what you'd be looking for : http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 2):

CSS will definitely give you a good start. You can check out what's possible using CSS by taking a look at the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/207/207.css&page=0). Each example there is composed of the same markup. The only thing that changes is the CSS applied to the page.

If that kind of stuff is all you need, then CSS will be fine. You can start learning CSS at [the W3Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

If that's not enough, you're probably looking for the interactivity that JavaScript brings to the plate. Luckily for you the [W3Schools has a section for that too](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the CSS Zen Garden link. I found the resources page very useful!

Answer (score 2):

CSS is really very Good Start. In most of the web development today, you will come across it. So, just learn it properly from :

[CSS from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Also, learn using Javascript & jQuery(Framework of JavaScript) with CSS as they all are integrated with each other. And will help you in development + designing.

For JavaScript : [JavaScript from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)
For jQuery : [jQuery from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)

I suggest use Dreamweaver for better learning.

If interested in Design Phase, CSS is basic for using with any other programming language, but gradually also go towards, Flash, Flex & etd.

Answer (score 1):

Every project starts with a plan. Make sure you understand CSS and look at some CSS Frameworks like 960 grid system http://960.gs

Also think about a template engine like Smarty http://www.smarty.net

You can also add javascript to your templates with for example jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: 960 grid system looks interesting. Speedy solution for simple layouts. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Developing user interfaces in most cases requires some knowledge of Javascript. 
Or at least a will of gaining new knowledge. Some useful features, made by Javascript are already created in such libraries, as jQuery, so you just have to initialise and tweak them. To create a website, where content is changed on-the-fly depending on user's input, you need to use AJAX, which could be also comfortably implemented using jQuery. Ofcourse, a product  should also be usable without Javascript, when you turn it off in your browser for example. That means, that the knowledge of CSS is relevant. What's to CSS3, it is like Javascript - everything should look nice without it, but it is a great addon for modern browsers. Besides CSS, you could read articles about design. Interface should use user-friendly colors, margins and placement of certain elements.

I learned CSS, Javascript ad AJAX reading [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp), but ofcourse, the best practics is to make something yourself. And the more you make, the better it gets. Here is the description of [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) library. On the net, you can find lots of plugins for interfaces, such as accordions, fall-out windows, pop-up tooltips, sorted tables and other. A great site, where you can get most of useful stuff is [Leigeber.com](http://www.leigeber.com/) . The scripts there are small and fast.

Good luck!